# Converting a normal PNG to iPhone Optimized format

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an iPhone application that downloads images from the internet and saves them for display later.

The user can select the images to view from a UITableView, the table view has custom cells which display thumbnails of the original images in varying sizes.

When the large image is first downloaded it is scaled to thumbnail size and the thumbnail is saved using UIImagePNGRepresentation.

What I would like to do is save the thumbnail in the optimized iPhone PNG format.  How can I do that? does it happen magically just by loading the original large image into memory and saving it? Do I have to do any further processing on the thumbnail before saving?

Comment: Good question. I know XCode does it when copying pngs to your app, but don't know how you'd do it dynamically.

Comment: Isn't it most likely that the optimized PNG format is automatically used when an image is saved using UIImagePNGRepresentation?

Comment: I doubt it. The "optimized" PNGs are non-comformant and can't be read by anything but the iPhone image decoder

Answer (score 2):

Chances are the UIImagePNGRepresentation does not create the images, as they are non-comformant PNGs, and can't be read by anything else. If they API generated PNGs that could not be read I think it would document that, and anyone who uploads PNGs from the phone would notice that they did not work.

The optimization is useful, but most of the optimized PNGs are part of the UI where the optimization is done as part of the build process. Chances are the cost of performing the optimization will offset any gains you get from it.

Comment: Not my images, they come from the web so are not optimized for the device. If I COULD save the images in an optimized format then the cost you mention would be one-time and at a time the user is already in 'waiting mode'.

Comment: Sure, but two points. First off, it would be a lot of work. Second optimized PNGs are more efficient than normal PNGs, which are necessary for lossless content (like the UI). A lot of web content is lossy stuff (JPG), and the increase in file size costs more than the decompression. Remember the device flash is slow, reading a 60k file takes longer than a 12k one. If your original source something lossy just uses JPGs.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the RGB565 colorspace used in the optimized format is simply not available in a CGGraphicsContext, which is the rendering class used by all the UIwhatever components.

So if I DID write some code to change the color space of the image before saving it, I couldn't get the texture back into a UI class.  The only way to use it is to load it directly into the OpenGL innards and use OpenGL in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the "optimized PNG" format, as it isn't making any significant difference.

It [does not affect rendering speed at all](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/), and loading speed is [dictated by file size more than file format](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html).

So simply save it in a format that will give you smallest files. If you're not using transparency, then it might be JPEG.

If you need transparency, and can spend more CPU time when saving images, then include [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) in your program (it's under BSD-like license) and shrink those PNGs to 8-bit palette.