# What's the most optimal PNG internal format for iOS display can be generated from non-Apple platform?

Tags: image, ios, optimization, png

PNG is recommended, fastest format for iOS. However PNG itself have several internal sub-formats. Alpha channel, byte ordering, color depth and etc.

I read [Converting a normal PNG to iPhone Optimized format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184385/converting-a-normal-png-to-iphone-optimized-format) but the Q/A is about to images in bundles. Now I'm generating many thumbnails optimized for iOS from *server*. I can't use Apple's framework on server. However sub-optimal format is enough too. I want to hear opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that [Xcode-optimized PNGs are overrated](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html) simply creating smallest possible file may be a better option, and [pngquant](http://pngquant) + [PNGOUT](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm) or [AdvPNG](http://advancemame.sourceforge.net/doc-advpng.html) are good tools for that.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS SDK runs pngcrush on the images it puts in the application bundle. Looking at the settings it uses would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer\
/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush \
-revert-iphone-optimizations -q Local.png Local-standard.png
```

see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1681/_index.html