# How to create a PNG image with the smallest size and good enough for web?

Tags: c#, image, image-compression

I have a png image of `172kb`. Opening it on an image editor and saving as `png-8` it becomes `39.3kb` and if I set as `gif` it becomes `42.06kb`.

In c# I tried to save as `png` and the size doesn't change at all. I tried to save as `gif`, the quality gets awful...

How can I get the same size with `c#` and keep a good quality to show on the web?

Comment: beauty is in the eye of the beholder

Comment: Do you have to use C#? MS Paint actually does a pretty darn good job at compressing (regular) PNGs (it has an adaptive filter)

Comment: What exactly is your scenario? Why do you need good on-the-fly compression in C#?

Comment: @Cameron I need something to lower the size of images on an existing website. An user can upload any image and I have to compress and save it.

Comment: @Bruno: Got it. Have you considered using an external service (like calling out to the system and using ImageMagick?)

Answer (score 0):

Check this site http://imageoptim.com/
The author says his solution will make your PNG 1/3 size average without loosing PNG compatibility. And it can be even smaller if you can afford lossy compression.

This link gained from QA thread here: [What's the most optimal PNG internal format for iOS display can be generated from non-Apple platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334418/whats-the-most-optimal-png-internal-format-for-ios-display-can-be-generated-fro/9826748#9826748)